# ModuleNotFound error in Python but directory is on sys.path

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

Ok, so here is my directory structure

```
company
└── team
    └── user_utils
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── test.py
        ├── utils.py
```

from the root of my project - which is at `/user/user4769/development/python-utils`

From the root I run :

`python3.8 /user/user4769/development/python-utils/company/team/user_utils/main.py` or the same with `-m` flag. As expected, when I print `sys.path` the current directory of `main.py` is added first - so I do see :

`['/user/user4769/development/python-utils/company/team/user_utils', ....]`

In my `main.py` I do have :

`import company.team.user_utils.utils`

But I do get `ModuleNotFound`

If I add this `sys.path.append(os.getcwd())` then `/user/user4769/development/python-utils/` which is my root folder gets added onto the path, and then import works.

What am I missing? This is Python3.8

Comment: If you run a python file like `python /some/directory/file.py`, the current directory is NOT added to sys.path.  `/some/directory` is.

Comment: `/user/user4769/development/python-utils/company/team/user_utils` is in the import search path, but `/user/user4769/development/python-utils/company` is not, so `import company.<whatever>` is not going to work. if you add `/user/user4769/development/python-utils/` then it will be able to find `company`.

Comment: The best solution is to package your project so that it is installable then `pip install` it, possibly using the `pip install -e` option so that it is an editable installif you want to keep developing it

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I will yes - but want to have a way to test local changes - and only way is to add at the end of the path the current directory, which I didn't thought is ideal.

Comment: @ghostrider But packaging your project and then `pip installing` it would not prevent you from testing local changes. I don't mean upload your project to the Python package index, you don't ever have to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The (top) module you are trying to import is `company` so for this to work you need to have `/user/user4769/development/python-utils/` in your path, as you have also found out. And I believe there also needs to be `__init__.py` files in  the `company` and `team` directories. If you want to treat the `user_utils` directory as a location to import modules from, as implied by having pointing out it is in your path, a simple `import utils` will do.

The dot notation is only for importing submodules and elements from a hierarchical module with submodules. So if `company` was the module, with (one) submodule being `.team.user_utils.utils`.

**Note:** given that your import works with `.../python-utils` in your path, I'd wager that `company` is indeed a hierarchical module. If that is the case, `utils.py` may utilise elements from other parts of the `company` module, in which case importing it directly and not as a submodule may very well not work.